# Common voltage of 2 op amps instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, instrumentation-amplifier, common-mode, strain-gage

I am trying to build an amplifier for a strain gauge sensor using the 2 op amps instrumentation amplifier design provided in the Texas Instruments note: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa247/sboa247.pdf?ts=1605266073942&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F.
[image]

I was able to derivate the expression for voltage gain of the amplifier, but I have troubles understanding the expression for the common voltage gain and also why the total resistance of the bridge is 4 X 120.
[image]

Can someone provide an explanation for my dilemmas regarding the common mode voltage of this amplifier design? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't understand your dilemma and why you are confused. It's certainly confusing the 4 x 120 ohm bit but it's not clear whether you think it should be 4 x 120 or someone or something is telling you it's that and, a bridge doesn't really have a total resistance parameter because there are four terminals so, that's a little confusing too.

Comment: I don't think that the resistance should be 4 X 120 ohm, this is stated in the link that I provided. The expression for the common voltage is similar to that of a voltage divider, but I cannot work out the resistors that form the divider because of the strange term R_bridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just set R9 to be zero, and all bridge resistors to be 120 and the potential divider produces a ratio of 360/480 and clearly that's wrong because it should be 0.5. At this point, if I were you I'd ignore the document and find another I could rely on.

Moving on... just look at the glaring error putting R5 in the numerator when they meant R9 so, if I used R9 = 0 in that formula instead of R5 then it comes up with the right answer but, I'd be tossing this document in the bin for such glaring mistakes: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir! I also thought that the expression was quite strange, but I guess I was so focused on trying to understand the meaning behind it that I missed the obvious error :). Personally, I don't find any particular reason for including the resistor R9 in addition to the current limiting resistor R8.

Comment: @IlieRazvan - for a quarter bridge circuit you'd be daft to use either R8 or R9 when a pure voltage source (or better still a current source) would perform better - you'd get a stabler output voltage and a more guaranteed relationship between Vout and the change in value of R7 if you do and the maths show that a current source is slightly more linear than a voltage source hence, the circuit using R8, R9 is pretty naive. [Do you know what to do next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png) if you are satisfied with the answer. If not place another comment for clarification.